# Python: Selecting object by name in 2.8

Tags: python

The following:

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Sphere.017']
```

don't work in Blender 2.8, they did in 2.79 though.
How should I select (multiple) objects with Python in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38618/selecting-an-object-via-scripting/38626#38626

Comment: thanks for the help, i already check this topic and it didnt help me at all at resolving my problem

Comment: Regarding why "thanks" was removed from your question: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/why-is-saying-thanks-forbidden-here

Answer (score 60, accepted):

According to the [API changes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API):

> In 2.7x, you could directly (de)select an Object from its select property. This has been removed in 2.8x, in favor of some get/set functions.

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True    # 2.7x
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select_set(True) # 2.8+
```

*Proof using the Console:*

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"].select_set(True)
>>> bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"].select_get()
True
```

*API Link:* [docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.select_set](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.select_set)

---

Example on how to *select* a certain object in the scene and make it the *active object*:

```
ob = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]       # Get the object
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselect all objects
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob   # Make the cube the active object 
ob.select_set(True)                          # Select the cube
```

Example on how to select *multiple objects by name*:

```
for o in ("Cube", "Camera", "Light"):
   obj = bpy.context.scene.objects.get(o)
   if obj: obj.select_set(True)
```

Example on how to select *all objects of a certain collection*:

```
col = bpy.data.collections.get("Collection")
if col:
   for obj in col.objects:
       obj.select_set(True)
```

Comment: Found the answer...this works!!  obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['cube']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj

Answer (score 7):

adding thoses two lines work in 2.79, but not in 2.80

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = OB
OB.select = True
```

the api has change for this new version, so for 2.8 its

```
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = OB
OB.select_set(state=True)
```

so now my correct code is this

```
import bpy

OB = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='MIRROR')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', view_align=False, location=(bpy.context.scene.cursor_location))
OA = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]
bpy.context.object.name = "Mirror Axes"
OB.modifiers["Mirror"].mirror_object = bpy.data.objects["Mirror Axes"]
OB.select_set(state=True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = OB
OA.select_set(state=False)
open_menu("D Mirror Menu")
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `bpy.context.object = OB` throws an exception. `Context property "object" is read-only.`

In 2.79 and below, we can set the scene's active object with the scene's property:

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = OB
```

Comment: i already tried "bpy.context.scene.objects.active = OB" it dont work for me, 2.8, the empty is still selected

Comment: @Dorian The question doesn't say anything about 2.8...

Comment: the code change for a simple operation like that ? i didnt know that

Comment: @Dorian Yes, 2.8 works different in that area. Handling the context scenes and collections (which were only introduced in 2.8). I suggest you edit your question to include that info.

Comment: thanks for the info, i did, i aslo try it in 2.79, dont work either

Comment: @Dori If I execute this [code](https://codeshare.io/29K918), in the default scene in 2.79 (with the cube selected) it works as expected.