# How to get the collection an object belongs to?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, collections

I can access objects belonging to a collection like so:

```
objects_in_collection = bpy.data.collections["My_Collection"].objects
```

How can I access the collection a specific object belongs to?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Object.users_collection`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=users_collection#bpy.types.Object.users_collection) property returns a tuple containing all *linked collections*:

```
>>> obj = bpy.context.object
>>> obj.users_collection
(bpy.data.collections['Collection'],)
```

Comment: Many thanks!
I also needed to get the name of the collection and was able to do so like this:
ob.users_collection[0].name

Comment: @brockmann  :: Is the result always by order?   e.g. [0] = direct parent?   The official document in your link lacks detail.

Comment: Not sure, just test it. If not the case, you can sort it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146685/how-to-obtain-the-parent-of-a-collection-using-python/172581#172581 @cppBeginner

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Select this object by name and it should take you to the right collection. Selection by name is described [in this section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472499/blender-2-6-select-object-by-name-through-python).

Comment: *Selection* works differently in *Blender 2.8x*: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132829/31447