# How to move multiple objects into another collection?

Tags: python, scripting, objects, collections

I am using this code which works very well for one object. I select `Object_A` and it moves to the collection `MyCollection`. If I select two or more objects, how would I change the code?

```
bpy.data.objects['Object_A'].select_set(True)
obj = bpy.context.window.scene.objects['Protrusive']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
A = bpy.context.object
A_old_coll = A.users_collection
terrain_coll_name = "MyCollection"
if terrain_coll_name not in bpy.data.collections:
    terrain_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name=terrain_coll_name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(terrain_coll)
else:
    terrain_coll = bpy.data.collections[terrain_coll_name]

terrain_coll.objects.link(A)

for ob in A_old_coll:
    ob.objects.unlink(A)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to [`.unlink(object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.unlink) each object from all [linked collections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/134789/31447) and then [`.link(object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.link) each object to your target collection.

Example on how to move all objects in selection to `MyCollection`:

[image]

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

# List of object references
objs = C.selected_objects

# Set target collection to a known collection 
coll_target = C.scene.collection.children.get("MyCollection")

# Set target collection based on the collection in context (selected) 
#coll_target = C.collection

# If target found and object list not empty
if coll_target and objs:

    # Loop through all objects
    for ob in objs:
        # Loop through all collections the obj is linked to
        for coll in ob.users_collection:
            # Unlink the object
            coll.objects.unlink(ob)

        # Link each object to the target collection
        coll_target.objects.link(ob)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to get it to work. I have selected a few objects then run the code and nothing happens.

Comment: Make sure there is a collection called `MyCollection` as a sub-collection of the scene collection -> add a `print(coll_target)` before the check @MichaelTeiniker Btw: Wouldn't write an asnwer without testing it. More importantly try to understand the principle.

Comment: recommend `coll_target = context.collection`

Comment: @brockmann this case is if the "MyCollection" belong to the Scene Collection, but how to make it work if the "MyCollection" is a child of some other collection?

Comment: @JuanCarlos just use the following statement for a collection named "CollectionXYZ":
  
`coll_target = bpy.data.collections["CollectionXYZ"]`