# Batch export collections into GLTFs (Blender 2.8+)

Tags: python, export, gltf

This one would be a folowup on [Question 168140](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168140), but compatible with 2.8+ (2.82. to be exact).

What I'm looking for is any solution to batch export multiple collections into GLTFs, preferably the GLTFs bearing the collections names. Tried modifying a few older scripts to work, with no luck whatsoever.

Thanks for any ideas, pointers, or help in advance. (Please keep in mind I have little to no idea what I'm doing regarding to scripting)

Comment: *"Tried modifying a few older scripts to work, with no luck whatsoever."* What have you tried *exactly* to modify the script of the linked q?

Comment: Search for how to reveal the "Blender Console" on your platform, and take a look for error messages related to scripts you run.  You can even paste error messages from the script into your question.