# Export multiple objects to individual glTF files?

Tags: python, export, gltf

I'm looking for a tool to export 40.000 objects into the individual glTF files. Sorry, I don't have any basic Python knowledge so please allow me to ask for help. I found a [similar add-on on this site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5382/export-multiple-objects-to-obj/31852#31852), which does the job for OBJ files - would it be possible to make the same for glTF?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome! Bare minimum is to show some effort, please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Also please take the [tour] to learn about how this site works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add-on based on the answer of [**Export multiple objects to .obj**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/31447), adapted to **export all selected objects** to individual `.glb/.gltf` files.

[image]

#### `batch_gltf.py`

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>

# Based on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31852/

bl_info = {
    "name": "Batch Export GLTF",
    "author": "brockmann",
    "version": (0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 91, 0),
    "location": "File > Import-Export",
    "description": "Batch Export GLTF files",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Import-Export"}


import bpy
import os

from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

from bpy.props import (BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       StringProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       CollectionProperty
                       )


class ExportMultiGLTF(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    """Batch export objects as gltf files"""
    bl_idname = "export_scene.batch_gltf"
    bl_label = "Batch export GLTF"
    bl_options = {'PRESET', 'UNDO'}

    # ExportHelper mixin class uses this
    filename_ext = ""

    filter_glob: StringProperty(
            default='*.glb;*.gltf', 
            options={'HIDDEN'}
    )

    # List of operator properties, the attributes will be assigned
    # to the class instance from the operator setting before calling.
    batch_export_format: EnumProperty(
        name='Format',
        items=(('GLB', 'glTF Binary (.glb)',
                'Exports a single file, with all data packed in binary form. '
                'Most efficient and portable, but more difficult to edit later'),
               ('GLTF_EMBEDDED', 'glTF Embedded (.gltf)',
                'Exports a single file, with all data packed in JSON. '
                'Less efficient than binary, but easier to edit later'),
               ('GLTF_SEPARATE', 'glTF Separate (.gltf + .bin + textures)',
                'Exports multiple files, with separate JSON, binary and texture data. '
                'Easiest to edit later')),
        description=(
            'Output format and embedding options. Binary is most efficient, '
            'but JSON (embedded or separate) may be easier to edit later'
        ),
        default='GLB'
    )

    batch_export_copyright: StringProperty(
        name='Copyright',
        description='Legal rights and conditions for the model',
        default=''
    )
    
    batch_export_selection: BoolProperty(
            name="Selection Only",
            description="Export selected objects only",
            default=True,
            )

    batch_export_image_format: EnumProperty(
        name='Images',
        items=(('AUTO', 'Automatic',
                'Save PNGs as PNGs and JPEGs as JPEGs.\n'
                'If neither one, use PNG'),
                ('JPEG', 'JPEG Format (.jpg)',
                'Save images as JPEGs. (Images that need alpha are saved as PNGs though.)\n'
                'Be aware of a possible loss in quality'),
               ),
        description=(
            'Output format for images. PNG is lossless and generally preferred, but JPEG might be preferable for web '
            'applications due to the smaller file size'
        ),
        default='AUTO'
    )

    batch_export_levels: IntProperty(
        name='Collection Levels',
        description='Set the levels of collections',
        default=2
    )

    batch_export_materials: EnumProperty(
        name='Materials',
        items=(('EXPORT', 'Export',
        'Export all materials used by included objects'),
        ('PLACEHOLDER', 'Placeholder',
        'Do not export materials, but write multiple primitive groups per mesh, keeping material slot information'),
        ('NONE', 'No export',
        'Do not export materials, and combine mesh primitive groups, losing material slot information')),
        description='Export materials ',
        default='EXPORT'
    )

    batch_export_colors: BoolProperty(
        name='Export Vertex Colors',
        description='Export vertex colors with meshes',
        default=True
    )

    batch_export_cameras: BoolProperty(
        name='Export Cameras',
        description='Export cameras',
        default=False
    )

    batch_export_extras: BoolProperty(
        name='Export Custom Properties',
        description='Export custom properties as glTF extras',
        default=False
    )

    batch_export_apply: BoolProperty(
        name='Export Apply Modifiers',
        description='Apply modifiers (excluding Armatures) to mesh objects -'
                    'WARNING: prevents exporting shape keys',
        default=False
    )

    batch_export_yup: BoolProperty(
        name='+Y Up',
        description='Export using glTF convention, +Y up',
        default=True
    )

    def execute(self, context):                

        # get the folder
        folder_path = os.path.dirname(self.filepath)

        # get objects selected in the viewport
        viewport_selection = context.selected_objects

        # get export objects
        obj_export_list = viewport_selection
        if self.batch_export_selection == False:
            obj_export_list = [i for i in context.scene.objects]

        # deselect all objects
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

        for item in obj_export_list:
            item.select_set(True)
            #if item.type == 'MESH':
            file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "{}.{}".format(item.name, self.batch_export_format))

            bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
                filepath = file_path,
                export_selected = self.batch_export_selection,
                export_format = self.batch_export_format,
                export_copyright = self.batch_export_copyright,
                export_image_format = self.batch_export_image_format,
                export_materials = self.batch_export_materials,
                export_colors = self.batch_export_colors,
                export_cameras = self.batch_export_cameras,
                export_extras = self.batch_export_extras,
                export_yup = self.batch_export_yup,
                export_apply = self.batch_export_apply
            )
                
            item.select_set(False)

        # restore viewport selection
        for ob in viewport_selection:
            ob.select_set(True)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Only needed if you want to add into a dynamic menu
def menu_func_import(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ExportMultiGLTF.bl_idname, text="Batch Export glTF 2.0 (.glb/.gltf)")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ExportMultiGLTF)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menu_func_import)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ExportMultiGLTF)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menu_func_import)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    #bpy.ops.export_scene.multiple_objs('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

I added all relevant arguments of the `export_scene.gltf()` operator (line 179), you can change them or add new properties to the operator, wasn't sure.

---

For versions **pre 2.91**, replace the `batch_export_materials` property (line 117) using:

```
    batch_export_materials: BoolProperty(
            name='Export Materials',
            description='Export materials',
            default=True
    )
```

Related: [Batch exporting scene collections or selected objects using glTF-Blender-IO](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168140/batch-exporting-scene-collections-or-selected-objects-using-gltf-blender-io)