# Python: Check if object exists in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, objects

How can I check if the object exists in python?
I want to create an add-on but I'm unable to find any reference.
For example how can I check if "Cube" exist? If yes I will make another object green, if no I will make it red.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best practice is iterating through [`Scene.objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.objects) collection (*all objects of the current scene*):

```
import bpy

for o in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    if o.name == "Cube":
        print ("Cube found in scene")
```

Even easier to read is using python's [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) on the actual collection to get the reference:

```
cube = bpy.context.scene.objects.get("Cube")
if cube:
    print ("Cube found in scene")
```

Recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.scene.objects.get("Cube")
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

Alternatively you can also iterate through [`Data.objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendData.html#bpy.types.BlendData.objects) (all *objects of the actual file* using):

```
>>> D.objects.get("Cube")
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

For the sake of completeness, demo on how to get all objects starting with `"Cube"`:

```
import bpy

objs = []
for o in bpy.data.objects:
    if o.name.startswith("Cube"):
        objs.append(o)

if objs:
    print ("Cube found {} time(s) in file".format(len(objs)))
```

Related: [Python: Selecting object by name in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/132825/31447)

Comment: Am I allowed to use break and else?

Comment: Why not simply `if 'Cube' in bpy.context.scene.objects:` ?

Comment: Good idea, would have to explain why this works and that a `prop_collection` similar to a dict -  `__contains__` slot... get() is prefered and also returns a reference to work with, so I'd use it @MarkusvonBroady

Comment: I like dictionary keys method of the below answer. I use keys so frequently in regular python codes and so its great to use that than using ```get()```

Answer (score 2):

I use .keys()

```
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects.keys()
if 'Cube' not in objects:
     print("cube doesn't exist!")
elif 'Cube' in objects:
     print("Cube exists!!")
```

the same as dict.keys() in python dict returns a list of the objects names

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, however there's a few issues with your answer, which have resulted with a downvote: an answer already exists, but you didn't explain why your answer is a reasonable alternative to it; you didn't check your answer (there's a syntax error because of the apostrophe in the string); there's no point in calling `.keys()` method, as that will be the default iterator; instead of using `elif` you could just use `else` and make the code cleaner.

Comment: This answer is much better than the selected answer. Yes there is a syntax error but I really appreciate the key idea highlighted in this answer which is to use dictionaries something which we do so frequently in regular python codes. Also i appreciate the explicit usage of ```keys()```.