# How to access objects in Blender

Tags: python, scripting, objects, lighting

I found this code I want to use:

```
from mathutils import Vector
direction = Vector(your_tuple)
your_object.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
your_object.rotation_quaternion = direction.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
```

It says `your_object`. I tried to use `Area.001.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'` but it doesn't work. In that case my object is a area light. How can I transform the code to be able to use it with the area light from my scene ?

Comment: Object reference e.g. object in context: `C.object` or via scene `C.scene.object.get("Cube")`. Suggest use the python console to figure out: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html

Comment: I tried to use the console. The only output I get is `bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(extend=False, deselect_all=True)`

Comment: Thanks brockmann!

Comment: When I enter `C.scene.object.get("Area.001")` and hit enter I get this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'object'`

Comment: Seems I can accept the answer in at least two days.

Answer (score 4):

It's advisable to access objects via *context* members (`bpy.context`) since most of the available functions a.k.a [operators](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=operator#bpy.types.Operator) as well as entire UI is based on the *current context* by design. You can either use [`C.object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=context%20object#id4), [`C.active_object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=active_object#id2) (both are interchangeable) or access all selected objects using [`C.selected_objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=context%20object#bpy.context.selected_objects). Make sure the object is selected in the viewport/outliner and use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.object.rotation_mode # get the rotation mode
'XYZ'

>>> C.object.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION' # set the rotation mode
...
```

Based on that knowledge, it should be pretty straight forward to adapt the given script:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

C = bpy.context
obj = C.object

direction = Vector((1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
obj.rotation_quaternion = direction.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
```

---

If you'd like to access objects by their name, best practice to get the actual *object reference* is using pythons `get()` on [`Scene.objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scene%20objects#bpy.types.Scene.objects) collection. Using the index operator `[]` on [`Scene.objects`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=scene%20objects#bpy.types.Scene.objects) collection would raise a *KeyError* if the key is missing however (object name or index in this case). I'd suggest use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.scene.objects.get("Cube")
bpy.data.objects['Cube'] # object reference

>>> C.scene.objects["Cube1"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "Cube1" not found'

>>> C.scene.objects.get("Cube1", False) # get allows to provide a default value
False
```

See: [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405)

```
>>> obj = C.scene.objects.get("Cube")
>>> obj
bpy.data.objects['Cube']
>>> obj.rotation_mode
'XYZ'
```

Based on that knowledge, it should be pretty straight forward to adapt the given script:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

C = bpy.context
obj = C.scene.objects.get("Cube")

if obj:
    direction = Vector((1.0,0.0,0.0))
    obj.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    obj.rotation_quaternion = direction.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
```

You can also use `get()` on the object *data-block* of the current file [`D.objects.get("Cube")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html#module-bpy.data). However, might lead into potential *context* issues if eg. the object you're trying to access is no part of the current scene.

Related:

- [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)
- [Python: Selecting object by name in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/python-selecting-object-by-name-in-2-8/132829#132829)

Comment: I'm not sure how using get is best practice, since in the OP's case, if the object isn't in objects he's going to trigger an AttributeError on the attempt to use rotation_mode. ISTM that best practice is to handle the error where it occurs.  I suppose it's a dogmatic thing whether using a try block or testing the return value of get is better, but best practice would be to check the result in either case.

Comment: The reason is simple: `Scene.objects` collection supports it so there is no reason not using `get()`, see the linked stackoverflow post @MartyFouts

Comment: @batFinger is suggesting using the active object to avoid the dictionary lookup altogether.  I think that's a better approach as well, although it doesn't eliminate the error possibility of there being no active object when you run the script.  You really cannot robustly avoid dealing with the possibility that the script will be attempted when there's no object for it to operate on.

Comment: @brockmann If you look carefully at the answer with 200  score to the stackoverflow question you posted, it specifically states that there are times when you should not use get.  See my best practices comment in my answer for a quick summary; but they mention cases like this question: dont' use get when a default result won't do.

Comment: PEP8 does not advise against the use of try/except blocks. It even has a long section on how to create Exceptions and use them.  It recommends against using using of try/except in performance sensitive situations.  No, the exception can't be wrong, because exceptions are raised in the order generated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions:

```
from mathutils import Vector
direction = Vector([-1.0, 0.02, 0.1])
bpy.context.scene.objects[1].rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
bpy.context.scene.objects[1].rotation_quaternion = direction.to_track_quat('Z','Y')
```